# Python BeautifulSoup object returns nothing when find function is used

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get the content from this [website](https://www.justwatch.com/es/pelicula/la-vida-es-bella); to do so I wrote this code:

```
source = requests.get(justwatch+pelicula,headers=headers)
source_content = source.content
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(source_content,'html.parser')
soup2.find_all('div', class_='price-comparison__grid__row__element')
```

However I have achieve nothing as the `find_all()` as well as `find()`functions returns None.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you looked at "view-source:https://www.justwatch.com/es/pelicula/la-vida-es-bella"? You will see that the page is actually being dynamically generated, as most of the HTML content is not present. Therefore, you won't be able to get the content in this way, as a request like this will not execute the scripts on the page. You will need to look into using a tool like selenium in order to use a browser to access the page and execute the scripts.

Answer (score 2):

The site loads the data dynamically. from its api and the html of the site doesn't contain a `<div>` tag with `class='price-comparison__grid__row__element'`. That is why you get `None`. Try the python module [JustWatch](https://github.com/dawoudt/JustWatchAPI)

Run:
`pip install justwatch`

Comment: Thanks I didn't know they have an API

Comment: @sushiwithoutsushi if this answers your question, accept this as the answer so that the question is closed